# What are some fun things you can do using the ICSP header?

Tags: icsp

I bought 10 Arduino Nanos for a project, each with all of their headers soldered in place.  Each was going to go into a tiny space, so I found myself needing do desolder the ICSP headers.

This led to a bit of a moral conundrum.  What would I lose by removing these useful looking headers.  They cover quite a lot of space on the nano, so they must be important right?  Am I going to regret removing these things when I finally realize how useful they are (I thought to myself.)

In the end, I did remove the ICSP headers, but the event got my thoughts going.  What is this header all about?  Why is it there?  What can I do with it?  I began to search for things that I could do with the ICSP header, but engaging results were not forthcoming ( except for this project:  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/ParallelProgrammer )

Anyway, I was more interesting in things that flash, move, jump, sing, and such, so are there any interesting things that can be done with the ICSP header?

Comment: Mostly useless. You can always add them back if you need to, or use the other pins (as the ISP header pins are the same as pins 11,12,13,RESET,GND,VCC)

Comment: Are they the same pins for all Arduinos (mega, nano, etc.)?

Comment: Not necessarily. Pins 11, 12, 13 are MOSI, MISO, SCK on the ATMega328 based boards (like Uno and Nano).

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use *every single last byte* of flash on the device.

   Since you're performing low-level programming of the device you get the entire chip to play on, without having to worry about bootloaders and such.
2. You can debug (breakpoint, single-step, watch, disassemble, etc.) the code on the chip using software on your computer.

   Admittedly the devices you'd need in order to do so are more expensive than a simple ISP programmer and it only works with specific pieces of software, but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing I just came up with: you could use this header to attach a simple control panel for your Arduino.

Imbed the Arduino in any place/box/machine you like. Then use a cable with a 6 pin connector to connect the header to a small control panel.  The panel could have 3 buttons or LEDs, a reset button and a power plug.